# How to delete vertex and keep topology

Tags: qgis, intersection, topology, digitizing, nodes

I work with line vector data (road network).The lines (roads) includes several vertexes. I would like to have for each line only nodes - at the end of line, or at the intersection of n lines. How can I delete all the vertices, to have clean lines with nodes only, but keep the topology? When I delete vertex, the line topology is changed. My QGIS version is 3.8.2.

[image: In the first picture, the vertexes in red circle I would like to delete and the greens keep.]

[image: In the Picture 2, the line topology change is shown.]

Comment: This is not possible, since the vertices describe the geometry. Without vertice, no geometry. What is your final aim?

Comment: You could try the `Explode lines` tool: _"This algorithm takes a lines layer and creates a new one in which each line is replaced by a set of lines representing the segments in the original line. Each line in the resulting layer contains only a start and an end point, with no intermediate nodes between them."_

Comment: Ah, ok then, my aim is to make nodes, which represents the begining/end of the line, or the line intersection. Is it possible to make node from the particular vertex?

Comment: Thank you @Joseph that looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: You may be interested in the "Extract vertices" or "Extract specific vertices" tool or by the "Convert geometry type" tool

Comment: If you want to keep topology, that means the geometry can change? So e.g. if you have a curve, defined by 30 vertexes, you just want to keep the first and last vertex and delete the other 28, thus the curve being reduced to a straight line? Like this, topology remains the same, but not geometry - like in the example under "A continuous deformation (a type of homeomorphism) of a mug into a doughnut (torus) and a cow into a sphere" from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology  ?